# Changed timezone in php.ini but date() still not right

Tags: php, mysql, time

As the title suggests, I have edited the timezone in `php.ini`. I have ran `phpinfo()` to confirm this has worked and it has.

However, when I run `date('H:i');` it still shows the wrong time.

Why is this?

**EDIT:**

```
I expect 18:21
I get 3:21
UTC is 8:21
```

Comment: check if it shows time in (utc time zone)

Comment: Wrong in what way? It would be helpful if you could add both the wrong output and what you actually expect to receive.

Comment: @LauriK I have added what you asked for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the date_default_timezone_set() in your PHP program.

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
?>
```

Here's a guide: [PHP date_default_timezone_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_default_timezone_set(); function to set timezone